# What board to use to send a text message via an arduino board

Tags: arduino-galileo, edison

I am fairly new to arduino boards and I was wondering which board to use. I was looking into the edison board because it has built in wifi and bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

The [GSM Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield) will suit your needs. This is a *shield*, meaning that is a board that will go **on top** of another Arduino board (e.g UNO, Leonardo, ..., choose whatever you'll need).

This is what it will look like:

[image: Arduino UNO and the GSM Shield stacked]

To send SMS you'll also need a working **SIM card** and the **GSM library** to program the shield. On the previously linked page there are some tutorials to follow in order to check the basic functioning of the setup.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [Spark Core or Photon](https://store.spark.io/?product=spark-core).  It's not an Arduino but it's very close.  I have Arduino sketches that I have ported right over with no modification.

The Spark boards are internet-connected and you can send text messages or emails using IFTTT.  It's also going to be a lot more cost effective than an Arduino plus wifi shield, particularly if you can wait until June for the $19 Photon to ship.

You could also use a Raspberry Pi connected to the internet to just do the email part but that's a little more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I actually checked the price for the GSM shield and **Wow**, I didn't know that it was so pricey. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Arduino shields can definitely get pricey depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use a Raspberyy Pi if your project involves complex processing in it.
But if the project is very simple, just use one of those Spark Core or Photon.
Using an Arduino and a Sheild to do it is certainly **not** a good idea, as the Pi is much faster in processing and costs about the same.